# How to pass the context value to include template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to pass value dynamically to templates in Django and I have following code.
Help me with some suggestions.

view.py

```
account_detail(request):
 url = request.get_full_path()
 temp = url.split('/')
 id1 = int(temp[2])
 print url
 info = Patient_details.objects.get(id=id1)
 context = Context({'info': info,'id':id1})
 return render(request, 'patient/dashboard_d.html', context)
```

template1:

```
{% include "sidebar.html" with url={{ id }}%}
```

template2:
`<li><a href="../../{{ url }}/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>`

Comment: Whats the *exact* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have mentioned above,please go through the question before down voting it. I want to pass a value dynamically to a template that I am including in my parent template.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking about, What "value" are you trying to pass "dynamically"?

Comment: Remove the curly brackets and just use `with url=id %}`

Comment: i want to pass a section of the url  {% include "sidebar.html" with url={{ id }}%} with this line

Comment: @Selcuk no it dint work

Answer (score 2):

As a guess, I'm guessing your problem is with the include, you don't need to include the `{{ }}` tags.

```
{% include "sidebar.html" with url=id %}
```

Although when you use include, the context of the template you're passing to that template is also passed across so you could just do

```
<li><a href="../../{{ id }}/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Although, this is still wrong because you should be using the [`{% url %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: @AbhinavMishra - What does "it din't worked" entail? errors? invalid results? [ask]

Comment: nothing is passed to url in place of {{id}}